# Does anybody know how to generate 4 colors with new brightnesss based of a color in javascript?

Tags: javascript, colors

Hey I was wondering if anybody knew a way to generate some monochromatic colors based off a single color inputted in hex into a javascript function.

Comment: Do you mean you want 4 colors that are different levels of brightness but of the same hue as the input color? Not sure "monochromatic" is the right word to use here.

Comment: yeah, I am sorry for the confusion! I took the word from Kuler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is calculate the relative value for each color component against the average luminescence, then multiply each of these by a pair of offsets to generate different brightness...

This is pseudo-code, I'm sure you can figure out the details:

```
function getColors(baseline) {
  var offsets = [ 0x33, 0x66, 0x99, 0xCC ];

  // Use Jake's suggestion on computing luminescence...
  var lum = getLuminescence(baseline);

  var redCoefficient = baseline[red] / lum;
  var greenCoefficient = baseline[green] / lum;
  var blueCoefficient = baseline[blue] / lum;

  var output = [];
  for (offsetInd in offsets) {
     var offset = offsets[offsetInd];
     output.push(new Color(offset * redCoefficient, 
         offset * greenCofficient, offset * blueCoefficient));
  }

  return ouptut;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to raw Javascript, what are the colors being inputed as? An array?

Comment: Sorry, as I said - this is pseudo code - assumes you can figure out how to get the red/green/blue component of the baseline color, and compute luminescence - the other answers show you how to do this.

Comment: After a ton of hacking, this one works! Thanks to everybody for the help though, I did use all the code =D

Comment: Kyle - can you post your final solution so others (like me) don't have to go through the ton of hacking you did?

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to convert a color to some level of gray scale, try calculating the luminescence, like this:

```
function toGrayScale(color) /* color is an integer */ {

    // Extract the red, green, and blue portions of the color
    var red = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
    var green = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
    var blue = color & 0xff;

    // Calculate the luminescence
    var luminescence = red * 0.3 + green * 0.59 + blue * 0.11;
    var lumInt = Math.floor(luminescence);

    // Combine into a grayscale color
    return (lumInt << 16) + (lumInt << 8) + lumInt;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the 0.3, 0.59, 0.11 values please?

Comment: Hm, I was wondering about the Kuler-like monochromatic, where the colors "focus on varied lumicity and intensity while keeping the hue." Is this a HSV question?

Comment: @meouw, different applications use different formulas.  http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=448456 has a different set of numbers, where R = 0.2126, G = 0.7152, B = 0.0722.  It's subjective how to best map color to gray scale.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
// color looks like 0xRRGGBB
function(color){
    R = color.substr(2, 2)
    G = color.substr(4, 2)
    B = color.substr(6, 2)
    return "0x" + R + R + R
    // or return ["0x"+R+R+R, "0x"+G+G+G, "0x"+B+B+B]
}
```

By the way: "monochromatic color" is an oxymoron, isn't it? ;-)